# Button inside modal is not working with Bootstrap 4 but is working with Bootstrap 3

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Im working in a laravel project and I can use a button in order to show a modal and I have a delete button inside this modal and is working using botstrap 3 but is not working using bootrsap 4. ¨

This is my html code,
these CDN are working:

```
   <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and when I use these cdn my delete button inside my modal doesnt work anymore:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

My modal:

```
 <div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-cliente">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-orden_de_compra"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h3 class="text-center">¿Estas seguro de que quieres eliminar este pedido?</h3>
                    <br />
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id">id:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_delete" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="orden_de_compra">Orden de compra:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="name" class="form-control" id="orden_de_compra_delete" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span id="" class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete
                        </button>this delete button doesnt work with Bootstrap 4 but is working with bootstrap 3
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Close
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My js:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


   // delete a post
        $(document).on('click', '.delete-modal', function() { //this function works with bootstrap 4
            $('.modal-orden_de_compra').text('Delete');
            $('#id_delete').val($(this).data('id'));
            $('#orden_de_compra_delete').val($(this).data('orden_de_compra'));
            $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
            id = $('#id_delete').val();
            orden_de_compra = $('#orden_de_compra_delete').val();
            alert(id); 
        });
        $('.modal-footer').on('click', '.delete', function() { //this function doesnt work with bootstrap 4
            $.ajax({
                type: 'DELETE',
                url: 'posts/' + id,
                data: {
                    '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    toastr.success('Pedido eliminado exitosamente!', 'Notificación', {timeOut: 5000});
                    $('.item' + data['pedido_id']).remove();
                    alert('.item' + data['pedido_id']);
                }
            });
        });

</script
```

Comment: I've made a [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/gjLoMx?editors=1010) to reproduce the issue. Both BS3 and BS4 are there for a try (BS 3 is actually commented). In both situations, the red "Delete" is working fine.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Hi, try to use an alert function like this and you are going yo see the problem, in fact the problem is visible on your code, just change this function and add an alert $('.modal-footer').on('click', '.delete', function() { //this function doesnt work with bootstrap 4
  alert("hi"); // the alert is working on bootstrap 3 but is not working with bootstrap 4, the same occurs with any ajax function

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Basically when you click on delete button the modal closes but any function inside   $('.modal-footer').on('click', '.delete', function() { is not working with Bootstrap 4

Comment: Okay... I see. With BS4, the modal just closes... mmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I will do both snippets for you to see the difference.

BS3:

```js
$('.modal-footer').on('click', '.delete', function() { 
  console.log("I'm here.");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Open Modal</button>

<div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-cliente">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-orden_de_compra"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3 class="text-center">¿Estas seguro de que quieres eliminar este pedido?</h3>
        <br />
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id">id:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_delete" disabled>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="orden_de_compra">Orden de compra:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="name" class="form-control" id="orden_de_compra_delete" disabled>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span id="" class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete
          </button>this delete button doesnt work with Bootstrap 4 but is working with bootstrap 3
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Close
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After a look at the [Migrating to v4 documention](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#modal) and finding an absolute nothing about this...
I finally found it by comparing [the v4 markup](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) in search of what the %&* can be different.

It's pretty subtile... I don't know what `class="modal-cliente"` was for... Potentially something wrong that wasn't affecting v3. But it seems it is the issue with v4. The `role="document"` may be important too... Sorry, I can't explain in more details. ;)

Look for the 2 slightly changed lines in the markup below.

BS4:

```js
$('.modal-footer').on('click', '.delete', function() { 
  console.log("I'm here.");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Open Modal</button>

<div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <!-- Those 2 lines are slightly changed -->
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <!-- ============================ -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-orden_de_compra"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3 class="text-center">¿Estas seguro de que quieres eliminar este pedido?</h3>
        <br />
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id">id:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_delete" disabled>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="orden_de_compra">Orden de compra:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="name" class="form-control" id="orden_de_compra_delete" disabled>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span id="" class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete
          </button>this delete button doesnt work with Bootstrap 4 but is working with bootstrap 3
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Close
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I made a mistake because I put class="modal-cliente" instead  of modal-content, I didnt know that modal-content is a required class

Comment: Well... That mistake was hard to find! ;)